# Replacing Honeywell Thermostat (UK)

Tags: electrical, thermostat, central-heating, uk

Hiiii,

I'm in the UK and trying to replace an old battered thermostat. I have a Honeywell ST6100A and I'm looking to update to a Honeywell ST9400C. I somewhat naively thought that because it was the same brand, with the same backplate and an updated version that it might be the case of unplugging one and plugging in another.

I had a look at the diagrams for both, and the existing wiring, and of course noticed some differences there, particularly with the internal wiring, but fundamentally I didn't see much of a difference not to give it a blast. It worked. Ish.

So my setup had been ST6100A managing water and central heating. Heating set to cont. and a Nest E thermostat then controlling the heating for the house. Was all working well. When I made this change, though, the Nest E is no longer in control and cont. puts the CH into override and the whole house is heated. I'm guessing that there's probably a fairly simple wiring fix here, but I want to consult wiser minds...

Looking for the same setup - programmer controlling the water, always on for heat and Nest E controlling the heat.

Have attached pics of the wiring and both units' diagrams. Any help greatly appreciated.

OLD ONE & WIRING
[image]

[image]

NEW ONE
[image]

Comment: This is probably gonna be a toughie for most of us US-based folks—our thermostats typically operate on low voltage.

Comment: Pole "1" works differently on the new model.  You're not going to learn anything else from these photos.

Comment: There might be a simple wiring fix, but we would need more details. Mains Boiler wiring is not super standardized, and there are multiple ways to wire the same system with the same components to get similar results.

We would really need to know what is at the other end of the black, other black, gray, and red wires. 

The old system acting as a single dry contact relay (and was not wired to act like a wet contact relay), and the new one acts as two wet contact relays, so wiring changes are needed. The existing wiring seems to be using unused terminal 3 as handy terminal block.

Comment: The diagram on the old one suggests it was only controlling heat, not hot water.  That seems to be incorrect, so I wouldn't take the setup at face value. There are some older setups (eg gravity fed) where you get either hot water or heat+hot water (never heat alone) but it doesn't sound like one of those systems.